# change permission of directory and all its sub-directories/files recursively

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown, administration

I have search around but can't find the correct answer.

How do I change the permission of a directory and all its sub-directories/files then also when a user creates a file or directory this must also follow the same permissions set at the beginning.

Basically this is what i want to do:

Keep in mind I am running a Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 with 2 virtual hosts (so 2 separate IP's used)

1. create a new virtual host (i have completed this)
2. create a new directory `/var/www/example` (i have completed this)
3. created new group and user with the same name(as i wanted to mimic the same as www-data user and group.)
4. change ownership of directory:
   -- used command: `sudo chown -R user:group /var/www/example` (this change the owner to my desired owner and group owner)
5. set permissions of this directory to 775 
   -- used command: `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/example` (this changed the permissions)

after all of these done i am still able to use a user to create a file which is good as this user is in the group i created but the thing is that the permissions are all wrong and the file owner is also wrong. (the user i used is also part of another group that is used on the other virtual host).

Please guide me to a solution. thanks

Comment: Check this: https://superuser.com/questions/381416/forcing-group-and-permissions-for-created-file-inside-folder#381525